# WritableSheet does not create sheet properly using groovy

Tags: groovy, worksheet

Soap version used-5.0.0

I am trying to create an excel sheet and write data into it using groovy script. My code is given below:-

```
import jxl.*;
import jxl.write.*;

WritableWorkbook wb = 
    Workbook.createWorkbook(
        newFile("/Users/anant/Downloads/GroovyTest/report.xls"));

WritableSheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Report Worksheet", 0);

Label label = new Label(0, 0, "hello");

sheet1.addCell(label)
```

Now the problems that I face are:

1. The excel sheet gets created in the given location but whenever I try to open it, it says that someone else is working on the sheet and hence I have to click either 'Read-only' or 'Notify' options
2. Now, I click 'Read-only' and then another message appears something like this- 'The type & extension of the sheet does not match and it is corrupted.Should you open it?'. On clicking yes, the excel sheet opens but the name of the sheet is not 'Report Worksheet' but takes the name of the excel workbook 'report' and also the "hello" text does not get entered.

Please suggest where am I getting wrong. I tried several times but the same issue happens even in other systems as well.

Comment: soap? What do You mean?

Comment: I am running this groovy script in soap ui 5.0.0

Comment: Can anyone please help me out on this???

Comment: 1. because is not closed in your program.

Answer (score 1):

After `sheet1.addCell(label)`

You should `write` and `close` the workbook according to the [doc](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableWorkbook.html#write())

```
wb.write()
wb.close()
```

Comment: @Shreyashi Glad it helps. You can accept my answer. (^o^)/